# What is the order of the element $5$ in the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$?

Tags: number-theory, permutations

I've looked up the definition for the order of an element a of a group; it is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $a^m = e$ (where $e$ denotes the identity element of the group, and $a^m$ denotes the product of $m$ copies of $a$).

I'm assuming that the identity element $e = 1$ for this group?

So would that mean I want an integer $m$ such that $5^m = 1$? If this is the case then $m = 0$, but I'm not sure if this is the right answer.

Comment: Do you know what the definition of the order of an element in a group is?

Comment: I just looked up what the definition is and have edited my question accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out, I was just guessing the definition based on my (poor) knowledge of this topic!

Comment: For additive group, isn't the identity e = 0?

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. But then if $e=0$ then we want $5^m = 0$ which doesn't have any solutions?

Comment: For additive group, the operation is + not *. $5^m$ translates to $5*m$, i.e., $m$ copies of 5?

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks! Sorry for my ignorance. So instead of $5^m = 0 $ we want $5*m = 0$, hence $m=0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite. You want the smallest ***positive*** $m$ such that $5m=0.$

Comment: Notice that if 0 were an acceptable order, than every element would have order 0!